# Using custom Oid in Subject Alternative Name with Bouncycastle

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am generating a certificate using BouncyCastle. Everything works fine until I am trying to add an Subject Alternative Name extension with GeneralName.OtherName an custom Oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3 (it stands for User Principal Name (UPN)). So the result should be like:
Subject Alternative Name section -> OtherName -> User Principal Name=user@domain

I am doing it like this:

```
Asn1EncodableVector vector = new Asn1EncodableVector
{
  new GeneralName(GeneralName.OtherName, 
                  new KeySpecificInfo(new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"), new DerOctetString(GetBytes("user@domain"))))
}
DerSequence seq = new DerSequence(vector);
GeneralNames subjectAltName = GeneralNames.GetInstance(seq);
// Adding extension to X509V3CertificateGenerator
certGen.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltName);
```

And after it I receive a strange serialized result in the SubjectAlternativeName section of the created certificate. It is obvious that adding OtherName section is wrong, but I could not find any information about adding custom oid for BouncyCastle.
Any ideas?

Comment: Java or C#? Which versions of libraries are you using?

Comment: C# but I also tried Java (there is some difference between them).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/jscep/jscep). It's Java but the code is practically the same for C#.

Here is my version in C#.

```
Asn1EncodableVector otherName = new Asn1EncodableVector();
otherName.Add(new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"));
otherName.Add(new DerTaggedObject(true, GeneralName.OtherName, new DerUtf8String(siteName)));
Asn1Object upn = new DerTaggedObject(false, 0, new DerSequence(otherName));
Asn1EncodableVector generalNames = new Asn1EncodableVector();
generalNames.Add(upn);

// Adding extension to X509V3CertificateGenerator
certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, new DerSequence(generalNames));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also for a C# bouncycastle cert:

```
//Subject Alternative Name
if (! (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_subjectAlternativeName))) {
    //Here we signify ip address instead of DNS SAN. This could be condition upon further development.
    GeneralNames subjectAltName = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.IPAddress, _subjectAlternativeName));
    certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, subjectAltName);

}
```